# ViewControllerApple.Apple.Type does not have a member named appleQuantity

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a UITextField named 'appleQuantity', when I try to convert it to an int to do math with it, it gives me an error named 'ViewControllerApple.Apple.Type does not have a member named appleQuantity'

Here's the code, the error is in 'var b:Int=appleQuantity.text.toInt()'

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerApple: UIViewController {
//80, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 2, 20, 2, 2
class Apple {
@IBOutlet weak var appleQuantity: UITextField!
@IBAction func addApple(sender: UIButton) {
    }

var b:Int=appleQuantity.text.toInt()
  // var appleCal = 80 * b

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

I'm Really new to swift, so the more details provided, the more helpful it is!

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: To improve the chances of someone answering your question, please only post relevant code - figuring out what this is often helps you answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED Answer:
I feel that you're thinking of things the wrong way slightly. Here is how I propose you try and achieve what you're doing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerApple: UIViewController {

  class Apple {
    var b: Int?

    init() {

    }

    func getAppleCalculation() -> Int {
      if let unwrappedB = b {
        return unwrappedB * 80
      }
      else {
        return 0
      }
    }
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var appleQuantity: UITextField!
  @IBAction func addApple(sender: UIButton) {

  }  

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This is where the view has loaded. Your buttons and textviews will
    // have loaded and you can perform any actions on them.

    var apple = Apple()

    if let unwrappedAppleQuantityInt = appleQuantity.text.toInt() {
      apple.b = unwrappedAppleQuantityInt
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```

OLD ANSWER: Your variable b will actually never contain anything except the default value.

You should assign your Int b in your class' viewDidLoad, or following your structure, in your object's init function:

```
class Apple {
@IBOutlet weak var appleQuantity: UITextField!
@IBAction func addApple(sender: UIButton) {
}
var b: Int

init() {
  if let unwrappedAppleQuantityInt = appleQuantity.text.toInt() {
    b = unwrappedAppleQuantityInt
  }
  else {
    // assign b a default value
    b = 0
  }
 }
}
```

or you could do return a computed value, provided you only care about the output rather than storing the value, like so:

```
var b:Int {
  get {
    if let unwrappedAppleQuantityInt = appleQuantity.text.toInt() {
      return unwrappedAppleQuantityInt
    }
    else {
      return 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But now, the line i had commented out previously "var appleCal = 80 * b" gives me the same error. Is there anything i need to change in order for it to work?

Comment: What are you specifically trying to do? Defining your IBOutlets in your Apple class is probably the wrong way of doing it. I will amend my answer with what I propose you do